# use google-chrome to programatically open/refresh links in the browser from linux command line

Tags: bash, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, tmux, tmuxinator

when i am working from the command line, i often use some shortcuts to open links in google-chrome.

i do that for example with:

`google-chrome "https://stackoverflow.com" "https://github.com"`

now i have to things i like to solve:

1. when google chrome isnt open yet: chrome will be launched with the link. This is fine, except the fact, that google-chrome automatically closes, when i close my terminal. How can I have it in the way, that chrome stays open, even when i close my terminal from where i launched chrome?
2. when google-chrome is already open, i sometimes already have the link openened, which i then open in a second tab again. so i have the same link opened twice. This often happens, when i relaunch my [tmux](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tmux/)-session with [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) QUESTION: how can i programatically check (for example with bash) if the link, the command tries to open, is already open? I want to do a refresh for that case.

Do you have any tipps for automating this, which tool i can best use for that? Maybe there is an api for google-chrome my code can talk to or is there some chrome app i can use for that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe ChromeDriver could help. It can be used in Python and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For first part of question:

```
nohup google-chrome "https://stackoverflow.com" "https://github.com" &>/dev/null & disown %%
```

I can't explain how this works. But it works :-) Found somewhere on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

From a  long time, but: 
"&" is to free the cursor and be able to use the terminal 
"nohup" is to run and not die when closing the terminal

Most of the times, only the "&" is fine. Try it like this...

```
# open the terminal
google-chrome "https://stackoverflow.com" "https://github.com" &
# hit enter to get the prompt back and close the terminal with Ctrl+d
```